# Python: Get text between two strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question. I am trying to get a certain string between two substrings from a text file.

The text file is larger, but part of it contains this:

> r\n[url=asitename][/url]\r\n[url=x]hello[/url]\r\n[url=x]a text[/url]\r\n[url=n]test[/url]\r\n\ttest
> \r\n\t\t\r\n\t\twarn user\r\n\t\r\n\t2\r\n\t02-06-2017, 01:44 am
> by cinccino. end: modcp_reports_report -->

Now, I am interested in the text next between 'asitename' and 'end:'

I would like to get the text between those strings.

I have tried this:

```
lookup = 'asitename'
myFileread = myFile.read()
re.search(lookup+'(.*)end', myFileread).group(1)
```

However, it returns the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

I am confused as to why this is not working. It works with more simple strings.

Comment: Can you share the output you want?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`re.S`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag which will make `.` match the new line character(s) also:

```
>>> re.search(r'asitename(.*?)end', myFileread, re.S).group(1)
'][/url]\r\n[url=x]hello[/url]\r\n[url=x]a text[/url]\r\n[url=n]test[/url]\r\n\ttest\n\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\twarn user\r\n\t\r\n\t2\r\n\t02-06-2017, 01:44 am\nby cinccino.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Return None if no position in the string matches the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the string.

It seems .search() is returning None. According to the python api this means there is no position that matches the pattern.